# Debugging HTTPS local services from my mobile device (web, api, websocket)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, https, localhost

Having a hard time debugging from mobile device my local development web app which connects to a GraphQL node server and another service using web sockets. All three services running on HTTPS to the below ports.

```
Web Reactjs app: https://localhost:3335
Node server: https://localhost:3334
Web socket server: wss://localhost:4443
```

From my macOS machine, everything works as expected but when trying to access the reactjs from Chrome Android and using the inspect desktop devtools and USB cable navigating to `https://localhost:3335` works but I get the error `POST https://localhost:3334/dev/graphql net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`.

My iOS device doesn't even connect to localhost:3335 or 192.168.2.3:3335.

I am open to any tips, tricks, services, and ideas to debug using my local development machine and mobile devices.

Comment: I would think it has to do with using `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost`. That could also explain why the CERT_DATE_INVALID error came up.

Comment: localhost:3335/ returns this page isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by navigating to all addresses in the mobile browser and accept the risk of a self-signed certificate.

`https://localhost:3334/dev/grapqhl` -> accept
`https://localhost:4443` -> accept

Now `https://localhost:3335` will work fine.

Struggling with iPhone debugging due to localhost not binding to the machine IP address (Pending solution, might create another SO question for reference).